# how to routes localhost url in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working with laravel application. in my application I have controller function to view form as following.

```
public function create()
   {
            return view('projects.new');
        }
```

when view projects/new.blade.php file it is contain form. in this form fill and save it is generated new project in project table. now I need after save this form next page redirect to the collaborator.blade.php file in the same projects folder. and local host url as this

```
localhost:8000/projects/10/collaborators
```

this is my controller method

```
 public function projectcollaborators()
        {
            return view('projects.collaborators');

        }
```

and routes

```
Route::get('projects/{projects}/collaborators', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController@projectcollaborators',

]);
```

how can I manage controller and routes to success above requirements?

Comment: Use Eloquent ORM to save the posted data to the table and just do a redirect on the POST route. You showed us one line that basically returns the view. Please post your routes and controller functions to see what you've tried.

Comment: @Peter please see my edited qustion

Answer (score 0):

You should have a Route::post in your route file to capture the form submit,

say something like `Route::post('projects', 'ProjectController@create');`

The function that returns the view should be called index with a route like this: `Route::get('projects', 'ProjectController@index');`

In the create function you can use `Input()` to grab the information submitted by the form.

After grabbing the information you need you can then add the details to your projects table using Eloquent.

e.g.

```
$project = new Project();
$project->name = 'Name'
$project->fields = 'Text'
$project->save();
```

After inserting and saving the details into your database you can do a redirect to `projects/ID/collaborators` route using the redirect function.

You will also need to create a route for `projects/ID/collaborators` so you dont get a 404...

e.g. `Route::get('projects/{id}/collaborators', 'ProjectController@collaborators');`

Comment: what about may I use another controller like ProjectCollaboratorController for this

Comment: Yes. Just use whatever controller you're using and change it in the routes.